# Java: Remove all whitespace except for string fields

Tags: java, string

So for example I've got following expression stored as a String:

```
"val : title = "Hello, World!"  ;"
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
"val:title="Hello, World!";"
```

That is without touching the value in " " quotes

Comment: In general, you might need a parser to do this.

Comment: Can't we replace `" "` with `", "`?

Comment: You can try [`"val : title = \"Hello, World!\"  ;".replaceAll("\\s+(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", "");`](https://ideone.com/Gzp7ut)

Comment: @YCF_L That looks like it's actually working; maybe this could be an answer?

Comment: @YCF_L Looks like it's working

Comment: Split the string by quotation marks, process the individual parts and join them back to a whole string.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there are a solution here [Regular expression to select all whitespace that isn't in quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577930/regular-expression-to-select-all-whitespace-that-isnt-in-quotes) this is a famous problem

Comment: @YCF_L Yeah, I should've found it in a first place.

Comment: @Stefan maybe not a duplicate since he didn't ask specifically for regex, but a solid answer for sure. i tried to regex it, too, but the guy in that post is a level above me

Comment: Okay thank you all for the answers, I marked it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to cycle over each character of the string, performing the following:

- if the current character is not a whitespace, append the current character to the output string
- if the current character is a whitespace and you are inside a string, append the current character to the output string
- if the current character is a whitespace and you are not inside a string, skip to the next character

So basically, one boolean to keep track of the state you are in (string or not string) whose value will be changed each time you find a non-escaped double quote (that is, " not preceded by ), and a for cycle looping through the string using the above boolean to decide whether or not to remove the whitespaces