# Golang replace all whitespace not between quotes

Tags: regex, go

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577930/regular-expression-to-select-all-whitespace-that-isnt-in-quotes) quote about replace all whitespace not between quotes, but Ihave recently started using golang, and it is saying that perl type regex is not supported in golang. Is there any way to replace all whitespace in golang using regex.

If there is a way to do this exclusively with regex, I would appreciate it.

examples:

```
A B " C" -> AB" C"
A B ' C' -> AB' C'
A B ` C` -> AB` C`

A B \'C\' -> AB\'C\'
A B '\` C \`' -> AB'\` C \`'
A B "\' C C \"\'\"" -> AB"\' C C \"\'\""
```

Comment: I doubt you may get the 100% safe pure Go regex solution due to the lack of lookbehind support. [This demo](https://play.golang.org/p/YI7mfCb1p-w) will do the job in most cases: ``regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|` + "`[^`\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^`\\\\]*)*`" + `|\s+`)`` and then ``r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(test, func(m string) string {
                if (strings.TrimSpace(m) == "") {
   return ""
  } else { 
   return m 
  }
        })``

Comment: Even if RE2 supported lookahead and lookbehind, how is something like `\s+(?=((\\[\\"]|[^\\"])*"(\\[\\"]|[^\\"])*")*(\\[\\"]|[^\\"])*$)` more understandable than a few lines of procedural code. Write code for the future readers of the code, not for some vanity metric of fewest lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> replace all whitespace not between quotes.
>
> examples:
>
> ```
> A B " C" -> AB" C"
> A B ' C' -> AB' C'
> A B ` C` -> AB` C`
>
> A B \'C\' -> AB\'C\'
> A B '\` C \`' -> AB'\` C \`'
> A B "\' C C \"\'\"" -> AB"\' C C \"\'\""
> ```

---

Code must be correct and, to be correct, code must be readable. No correct or readable regexp solutions have been offered so far.

---

Parse the text in Go.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

// Remove all whitespace not between matching unescaped quotes.
func removeUnquotedSpace(s string) (string, error) {
    rs := make([]rune, 0, len(s))
    const out = rune(0)
    var quote rune = out
    var escape = false
    for _, r := range s {
        if !escape {
            if r == '`' || r == '"' || r == '\'' {
                if quote == out {
                    // start unescaped quote
                    quote = r
                } else if quote == r {
                    // end (matching) unescaped quote
                    quote = out
                }
            }
        }
        // backslash (\) is the escape character
        // except when it is the second backslash of a pair
        escape = !escape && r == '\\'
        if quote != out || !unicode.IsSpace(r) {
            // between matching unescaped quotes
            // or not whitespace
            rs = append(rs, r)
        }
    }
    if quote != out {
        err := fmt.Errorf("unmatched unescaped quote: %q", quote)
        return "", err
    }
    return string(rs), nil
}

func main() {
    tests := []struct {
        in, out string
    }{
        {`A B " C"`, `AB" C"`},
        {"A B ' C'", "AB' C'"},
        {"A B ` C`", "AB` C`"},
        {`A B \'C\'`, `AB\'C\'`},
        {"A B '\\` C \\`'", "AB'\\` C \\`'"},
        {`A B "\' C C \"\'\""`, `AB"\' C C \"\'\""`},

        {`A B " C \\"`, `AB" C \\"`},
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        out, err := removeUnquotedSpace(tt.in)
        fmt.Printf(
            "|| %v || %v || %v || %v\n",
            tt.in, out, out == tt.out, err,
        )
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-3cDwSaakIb

Output:

```
|| A B " C" || AB" C" || true || <nil>
|| A B ' C' || AB' C' || true || <nil>
|| A B ` C` || AB` C` || true || <nil>
|| A B \'C\' || AB\'C\' || true || <nil>
|| A B '\` C \`' || AB'\` C \`' || true || <nil>
|| A B "\' C C \"\'\"" || AB"\' C C \"\'\"" || true || <nil>
|| A B " C \\" || AB" C \\" || true || <nil>
```

Answer (score -2):

Go's built in regexp uses [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) which is fast and has a lot of features, but is missing a lot of important features such as look-ahead and look-behind.

Fortunately, you can use the [pcre (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Go library](https://godoc.org/github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre). Now the regex will work.

```
package main

import(
    "github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre"
    "fmt"
);

func main() {
    re := pcre.MustCompile(`\s+(?=((\\[\\"]|[^\\"])*"(\\[\\"]|[^\\"])*")*(\\[\\"]|[^\\"])*$)`, 0)

    string := `A B " \"C \"" D`
    replaced := re.ReplaceAll([]byte(string), []byte(``), 0);
    fmt.Printf("%s", replaced);
}
```

Comment: With PCRE, it becomes easier and less overwhelming, but the `\s+(?=((\\[\\"]|[^\\"])*"(\\[\\"]|[^\\"])*")*(\\[\\"]|[^\\"])*$)` pattern won't do all the job and won't do it well as it does not support correctly escaped quotes and does not support all three types of "quotes" OP mentions.

Comment: When i try to use this with `go get` i get this error `cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in`.

Comment: Also this regex does not meet with what I asked for, it does not work with ` or '

Comment: @the That is the regex you said you wanted to use from the other answer. Now with PCRE available you can find a more applicable regex from other questions which have asked the same thing, there's no need for a Go specific one. As for the `go get` problem, I dunno.